# When does Java flush an OutputStream?

Tags: java, outputstream

Java's `OutputStream` includes a `flush()` method that you can use to force it to write the buffered output to the file, socket, device etc.

I just noticed in an application of mine that it buffers quite a bit of data before flushing it to file and it made me curious: how does Java decide when it *is* time to flush?

I would assume that it would try to make some intelligent decision based on how much memory it has available and thus might flush more often when memory constrained. But this is only an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

`OutputStream` is an abstract class and doesn't implement any flushing behavior by default. When and how to flush the data is up to the concrete class that implements the `write` functions. Flushing strategies can vary widely. By default `BufferedOutputStream` uses a buffer size of 8,192 bytes. Flushing the data in large chunks minimizes the number of system calls when writing to an operating system resource, but adds complexity and latency since unflushed data can remain in the buffer for some additional time. The optimal buffering strategy will depend on the underlying device or channel being written to. If you want to make sure all previously written data is flushed at a certain point, call `flush` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Everything @jspcal says gets a +1 from me.  I'll add that the best way to answer your question is to look at the code.  The Java source code is generally pretty approachable.  You'd need to make sure that you knew what implementation is backing your OutputStream object if that's all you know up front.

The easiest way I know of to do this is to use a good debugger.  You can know for sure that you're looking at the right code by putting a breakpoint at the point of a call into the OutputStream object in question, like f.write() or f.flush(), and then stepping into the call.  I expect that you could figure out just when f.flush() is called for any particular implementation of OutputStream that you might be interested in.

If you're just generally interested, you could look at the JavaDoc for OutputStream, and it should give you a list of at least the most important of the standard classes that subclass that abstract class.

...had to try that doc lookup myself.  Here's what I got:

> See Also:
>   BufferedOutputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream, DataOutputStream,
>   FilterOutputStream, InputStream

with InputStream in the list, I guess these all aren't implementations of OutputStream.  I can see why they'd mention InputStream, OutputStream's input analog.

Turns out that **BufferedOutputStream** doesn't do anything at all interesting.  It defaults to a 8K buffer.  It flushes the buffer only A) when the supplied data to write out exceeds the space left in the buffer, or B) before the stream is closed.  I noticed one interesting bit.  If you write more than the buffer size in a single write() call, the code flushes the buffer and then just directly writes the new data to the underlying stream without going through the buffer at all.  So if you write something larger than the buffer size, the buffer will always be empty afterwards.  Makes good sense.  So if all your writes are larger than the buffer size, **BufferedOutputStream** doesn't really do anything.